# Происхождение названия "Кондакопшино"?

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Не смогла найти ничего по названию населённого пункта и ж/д станции Кондакопшино, расположенного на юге Ленинградской области. Единственное, похожее название носит город Кондопога в Карелии, но, учитывая сотни километров между ними, приходит на ум только случайное совпадение звучания.

Comment: На карте 1860 года эта деревня носит название Кондаконщина

Comment: Спасибо, не знал. Интересно, а почему об этом ничего нет в интернете?
Вы не путаете, именно КондакоНщина?
Есть к поминание о деревене Кондакопшино (Воймикула) или КондокоПшино, а вот КондакоНщина не наблюдаю.  Замена "А" на "О", и "щино" на "щино" в порядке вещей, а вот П на Н - только по причине описки...

Comment: А где карту 1860 года можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу скажу, ответа у меня нет. Но кое-какие соображения рискну высказать.

Скорее всего топоним основан на имени собственном — Кондакопша или Кондакопшин.
Иначе трудно объяснить конечную часть -ино, очень напоминающую притяжательный суффикс.
Подобные названия, кстати, есть не только в Ленинградской области, что только подтверждает эту версию.

Что касается "карельского следа", то расстояние в несколько сот километров не должно смущать, огромное количество петербуржских топонимов — исторические фино-угорские или на финских корнях основанные.
Кондопога — (по-карельски kondii + pohju) состоит из основ 1) "дальний","глухой","заповедный" и 2) "дно","основа"; можно перевести как "медвежий угол".
Можно было бы допустить, что это же kondii есть и в основе топонима Кондакопшино, но вторая часть мало похожа на финскую или карельскую, да и форма на -ино тоже в этом случае маловероятна.

Все-таки я определенно вижу в Кондакопшине основу "Кондак" — церковное песнопение или (менее вероятно) одно из тюркских названий какой-то хищной птицы, сокола, кажется. Вторая же часть ("Опша") напоминает  довольно частую украинскую фамилию Опша. 
Осталось найти какого-нибудь купца, промышленника или еще какую известную личность по фамилии Кондакопшин или Кондакопша.

===

Я посмотрел немного по источникам — и обнаружил, что населённый пункт упоминается в числе существовавших ещё во время шведского господства, т.е. до Петра. Это напрочь исключает происхождение от русской фамилии. Но на шведское (германское) происхождения тоже как-то не похоже. Придётся всё-таки признать финский (карельский) "след", тем более, что деревенька Кондакопшино есть и в Московской области, где никаких шведов отродясь не было. И идти на поклон к питерским краеведам.

Comment: Интересно получилось. Спасибо. Меня уже спрашивали(почему то не вижу этого сообщения) о наличии церкви в этом населённом пункте, её названии и других интересных вещах, но Кондакопшино настолько мало и непримечательно, что ничего найти не удалось. Летом туда съезжу, посмотрю.

Comment: Заинтересовало нас в своё время Кондакопшино тем, что через него был проложен Таицкий водовод в Царское Село и парки. Искали его. От водовода мало что сохранилось, каналы, заросшие травой, в полях и пруды Баболовского парка. В одноимённом дворце, в руинах, здоровенная гранитная ванна. Главная достопримечательность этого места.

Comment: На Подробной геогностической карте окрестностей Гатчины от 1852 года  http://vyritsa.ru/map/vyritsa_1852g.jpg  Кондакопшино (чуть левее Павловска) именуется "Воймикуля Кондакопшина". То есть на 1852 год деревенька имела название "Воймикуля" и принадлежала Кондакопшину.  Антропшино http://vyritsa.ru/map/vyritsa_1852.jpg (на другой карте тоже 1852 года лучше видно, расположенное южнее Павловка) называется  "Андропшина".

Вы правы, "кондак"  - церковное слово, "в визант. традиции представлял собой многострофное песнопение" и тд. Видимо, от него и произошла фамилия Кондакопшин.

Comment: Так про то, что такое кондак, у меня ни малейшего сомнения не было с самого начала. Чай не первый раз сталкиваюсь. А вот с самим названием не все понятно. Но об этом уже все сказали.

Answer (score 0):

Недалеко есть деревня Антропшино, так что окончание "пшено" финское и как оно расшифровывается, кто знает, наверное, поле. Конда это "род" переводится. Кондакопшино преводится "родовое поле", место где поселился род, племя. Такое у меня мнение.

Comment: Посмотрела, по фински "род" -"suku". Поле - "kenttä". Непохоже.

Comment: В финском нет Ш. Две согласные подряд - вообще большая редкость. 
Т.е. речь может идти максимум о "руссифицированном" финском названии. Или заимствовании из шведского.

Comment: На карте 1879 года (на самом верху карты) http://vyritsa.ru/map/vyritsa_1879.jpg  Антропшино имеет название "Антропшина". Деревенька кого? - Владение некоего Антропшина.  
Видимо, было слово такое "антроп", или имя.
"Алексей Петрович Антропов  — выдающийся русский живописец-портретист, автор монументальных росписей, академик Императорской Академии Художеств".

Comment: На карте 1852 года http://vyritsa.ru/map/vyritsa_1852.jpg Антропшино, расположенное южнее Павловска, именуют "АнДропшинА".

Comment: Это все в порядке вещей. необъясним было бы переход П<>Н.